# visual basic programming combo box issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

How do I use `environment.username` code on my app to show current system user in the combobox, or to list everyone who ever logged in that pc?

Current code:

```
Private Sub FrmLogin2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'loading the Computer user account in the current pc
    Dim WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Dim strUser = ""

    strUser = Environment.UserName
    lblDispalyWinUser.Text = Environment.UserName

    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SRD-WSJHBAP12\CALCTOOL;Initial Catalog=CalcToolDB;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select EmpNo, Username, Password from UserLogin ", con)
    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    'Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader

    con.Open()
    con.Close()

    Try
        con.Open()
        sda.Fill(ds)
        sda.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()

        'cboUsername.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        cboUsername.ValueMember = "Environment.UserName"
        cboUsername.DisplayMember = "Environment.UserName"

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
```

Comment: You mean cboUsername.AddItem ? Read more about the combobox object here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox

Comment: `con.Open()
    con.Close()`...lol, what's the point of that? Did you leave it there by accident?

Comment: `Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("can not open connection ! ")
    End Try` ...this is an anti-pattern. It's fine to hide the error from the user, but don't hide it from yourself. You should log the exception somewhere (e.g. a file, or windows event viewer) so you can inspect it and find the technical details of what went wrong.

Comment: Anyway...are you asking how to make your datatable the data source of your combobox? `cboUsername.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` needs to be uncommented for that to work.

Comment: Or are you asking how to pass the Environment.username value as a parameter to your SQL query, to restrict the results to just the current user? It's a bit unclear what the issue is, exactly. But if you want to do that, you can google hundreds of examples how to to add a parameter to a SQLCommand.

Comment: thank you ADyson for clarification(parameter to sql command)..im working on it now